# select2 set preloaded tags from html option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, jquery-select2

I have the following html, the `<option>` tags are generated by me (by php, more precisely symfony3)

```
<select
    name="simple_event[tagsList][]"
    id="js-tags-list"
    class="form-control"
    multiple
    data-tags="true"
    data-placeholder="add-category-separated-by-semicolon"
>
    <option selected>html</option>
    <option selected>select2</option>
    <option selected>jquery</option>
</select>
```

I use `select2` with the followig snippets

```
$("#js-tags-list").select2({tokenSeparators: [";"]});
```

I thought it would have put the 3 tags as preloaded data, but it actually only put them as preloaded "suggestions" (which I thought would have been the case if I had not put the `selected` attribute)

Is there a way to do this (i.e preload data) without needing to generate my javascript with my php (which seems really dirty to me) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you load the values from a database, Symfony already provides something that preloads data. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html